# The most idiomatic word for this context?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Members of group A cannot trust group B, or they hardly can trust group B.

> There is a _______ on the part of group A to trust in group B.

I initially used "problem" for that blank. Then I thought of "difficulty". What is an idiomatic suggestion for that context?

Comment: Consider *reluctance*.

Comment: . . .or many of the [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/reluctance) of *reluctance*.